# Can not catch WebDriverException for certain elements

Tags: c#, selenium, exception, appium, winappdriver

I have the following elements identified in a page object..

```
public WindowsElement usernameField => _session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("UserName");
public WindowsElement passwordField => _session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("Password");
public WindowsElement menuButton => _session.FindElementByXPath("//Button[contains(@Name, 'Menu')]");
```

I have a test with the following steps..

```
WaitForObject(usernameField)
usernameField.SendKeys("...")

WaitForObject(passwordField)
passwordField.SendKeys("...")

ClickButton("Sign In");

WaitForObject(menuButton);
menuButton.Click();
```

And below, here is my WaitForObject method..

```
// Wait for an Object to be accessible
public void WaitForObject(WindowsElement element)
{
       var wait = new DefaultWait<WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>>(_session)
       {
           Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
           PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
       };

       wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(WebDriverException));
       wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(InvalidOperationException));
       wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));
       wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
       wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NotFoundException));

       WindowsElement waitElement = null;

       wait.Until(driver =>
       {
           waitElement = element;

           return waitElement != null && waitElement.Enabled && waitElement.Displayed;
       });
}
```

The WaitForObject method works great for the usernameField & passwordField checks, but for some reason it fails immediately when passing in the menuButton. I know it was checking properly for usernameField & passwordField because I included some Console.WriteLines() to print out whenever it would detect one of those exceptions. As soon as it gets to the menuButton, nothing is logged it just fails immediately with a WebDriverException

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

Why would it not act the same for the menuButton? I have tried other approaches using while loops catching general Exceptions, but still it fails immediately when it gets to this element with a WebDriverException.

If I use a Thread.Sleep(10000) before trying to check for the element, it works fine and performs the click..

I am using WinAppDriver / Appium libraries.

Comment: Read about `explicit wait` https://www.browserstack.com/guide/wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Is the browser doing a full page turn after clicking the Log In button, or is logging in done via AJAX?

Comment: @GregBurghardt this is not a browser, its a Windows Application. I use WinAppDriver which is like a selenium wrapper

Comment: those lambda expressions are executed right then and there, correct?  So not sure the wait is working at all. Not familiar with WindowsDriver or these types... a little odd that the driver has a type of WindowsElement and that type is also used for gui elements.

Comment: @pcalkins yes thats one too, however I assumed by just catching WebDriverException it would catch all the ones associated

Comment: sry, I just deleted that comment... ( I had asked about ignoring WebDriverException)... I'm not sure I understand this code enough to be helpful... the wait.Until() just returns a bool?

Comment: @pcalkins yep exactly. And to answer your question about the lambda stuff I am honestly not sure. Just saw some other tutorials and this setup seemed to be the way to go. I know that it works much like a while loop, for the elements that it works with I will get a printout every second of it catching the exception and trying again so I am sure its nothing to do with the lambda stuff.

Comment: in a browser-based webdriver, a WebDriverWait will usually return the result of a certain driver method.... this wait doesn't really do that, but returns a bool (which certain Selenium methods would return...) I really think this wait is not working the way you expect it to.  For the elements that work are you getting 10 printouts? (10 seconds...)

Comment: @pcalkins thats the weird part.. so lets say if I intend to fail it right at the first step, I change that identifier to something bogus - it will print out all ten exceptions then fail the test. So I know that wait.Until is doing its job. When it gets to the menuButton part, no print out whatsoever. Its like it fails before it even gets there.

Comment: check menuButton object before you call the wait... that may actually be an exception...(?)

Comment: @pcalkins but its not even getting instantiated until its in the Wait

Comment: That would mean you are passing in a null?

Comment: @pcalkins ahhhh thats a good point! Maybe adding in a check to make sure its not null before returning? Hmm I do see what you are saying.

Comment: @pcalkins I see the problem... you were right to suspect the lambda expression. It looks as soon as I reference that element its trys to find it right then and there before it even gets to the wait.Until. Thank you for the conversation my friend, you helped me think of new solutions. I will find a fix for this and update here when I have it

Comment: it's also possible it's deferred... like a linq query would be... it's a reference, but it may not be executed until you call ".enabled" or ".displayed".  Regardless you might try using another selector for that button.  IDs seem like they should always be used in this context...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh wait, sorry, I looked at your code more closely. Basically what's happening is because the method parameter is asking for the type itself, when C# goes to hand in the element to WaitForObject, it tries to evaluate the "WindowsElement menuButton" expression when it's handed to WaitForObject. By changing the WaitForObject method to accept a delegate, you'll defer that evaluation until you're inside the wait.

You'll need to change your WaitForObject to be something like:

```
public void WaitForObject(Func<WindowsElement> element)

// Unchanged code here

wait.Until(driver =>
       {
           waitElement = element();

           return waitElement != null && waitElement.Enabled && waitElement.Displayed;
       });
```

THEN call it like:
WaitForObject(() => menuButton);
menuButton.Click();

Answer (score 2):

you can try using regex instead of button use '*'
as inspect.exe is not defining the tag i.e. button.

else go With finding the element with Name locator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this issue is actually not with my selector not working, I do not understand why XPath elements are not being passed to my WaitForObject method. In the debugger, I see the exception thrown whenever I first reference it (waitElement = element). The exception is thrown in the page object, completely bypasses the wait.Until even though the other two elements were passed just fine